# DateTime.Now Returning Different Months on Different runs

Tags: c#, .net, date

I need to get the current date so that i can write a log file.
I use

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")
```

But the month value-`mm` always keep changing.What im i doing wrong?

Comment: `mm` is "minutes", `MM` is months.

Comment: @AntonGogolev..ah okay

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

because `mm` stands for minutes, not months.

Answer (score 4):

"mm" is the format string for minutes, not months. You want to use uppercase M instead, so use the format `yyyy-MM-dd`. For a list of all date and time related format strings have a look at the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for custom format strings.